# Understanding the semantics of C pointer casts when applied to literals

Tags: c, pointers, literals

Is there any documentation specifying the meaning of a pointer cast applied to a literal in C?

For example:

```
int *my_pointer = (int *) 9
```

Is this compiler-dependent or part of the standard?

Edit: deleted misleading note based on comment below, thanks.

Comment: There are cases where we need to be specified directly and address of the port, such as embedded systems.

Comment: The standard doesn't say that there has to be an address 9, so this is non-standard.

Answer (score 5):

```
int *my_pointer = (int *) 9
```

This does not point to the literal `9`. It converts the literal `9` to a pointer to `int`. C says the conversion from an integer to a pointer type is implementation-defined.

```
int *my_pointer = &(int) {9};
```

This does. It makes `my_pointer` points to an `int` object of value `9`.

Comment: Is that actually OK? What's the storage of that int object?

Comment: @KerrekSB It's a compound literal and storage duration is static if `my_pointer` is declared at file-scope and automatic if `my_pointer` at block-scope.

Comment: So if it's automatic, does its life and at the semicolon?

Comment: I think if it's automatic the object's (the compound literal) life starts at the `}` of the initializer and ends at the `}` of the enclosing block where `my_pointer` is declared.

Comment: +1 for directing to compound literals. To be more precise, lifetime is not scope, the standard states *its lifetime extends
from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in
any way.* So its lifetime might well start before its declaration is met for the first time and it ends whenever you *leave* the enclosing block.

Comment: Lifetime and lexical scopes are certainly two different concepts, but still in C an object declared at file scope always has static storage duration and an object declared at block scope without any storage class specifier always has automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer to integer and integer to pointer conversions are implementation-defined (see Annex J of the C standard).